# Which algorithms provide high compression ratios for bit matrices?

Tags: algorithms, data-compression, matrices

I have an x*y bit matrix where the total number of bits fluctuates between ~1,000,000 and ~20,000,000 bits. The rows are much smaller than the columns. An example matrix might be of size 1,000,000 x 20. The percentage of 1's in this matrix is around 15% and these 1's can occur anywhere within the matrix, with the remaining bits being 0. Which algorithm(s) would provide high compression ratios for such a matrix, if possible? This matrix is generated on a node and has to be sent to another node, with any decompression information, to allow the receiving node to fully decompress the original matrix.

Comment: The key to data compression is modelling. If `these 1's can occur anywhere within the matrix` - there is no (other) redundancy to use - any "stateless" encoding using `around 15% [1 bits]` will do. But first try to throw the data at standard compression programs 1) "as is" 2) in "[Sierpiński order"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_curve) 3) switching between horizontal and vertical traversal: 32 bits ("word") horizontally, 32*24 words ("stripe") vertically, 24*18 stripes horizontally (oops, 10 Mbit already - maybe start with *byte*) 4)5) as 1)&2), but bits expanded to bytes .

Comment: Sorry I meant ratios. There are probably no other redundancies but i have added more information in the question about an example of the size of the matrix.

Comment: Please use a self-respecting general purpose compressor (better yet, two) on at least one smallish and one largish sample data set ("as is" and each bit represented by a character/byte) and include results in your question (and whether or not these seem to fit the assumptions `around 15% 1's` and `no other redundancies`). Have a look at [PAQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PAQ) (note the frequency of the words *improvement* and *model*). In case, use a version no older than 12 years.